# QtCreator: Target debug/...obj doesn't exist

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to C++ and Qt. My problem is, that I created a new class and it doesn't get compiled.
So the compiler says: "unresolved Object in ...". 
This is the header:

```
#ifndef TRANSITIOUSPLAYER_H
#define TRANSITIOUSPLAYER_H
#include <QtMultimedia>

class TransitiousPlayer
{

public:
    TransitiousPlayer();
    TransitiousPlayer(const TransitiousPlayer &other);
    ~TransitiousPlayer();

    void play();
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(TransitiousPlayer)
#endif // TRANSITIOUSPLAYER_H
```

class:

```
#include "transitiousplayer.h"

...

void TransitiousPlayer::play(){
    QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    QMediaPlaylist* playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
    playlist->playlist->addMedia(new QString("sh.mp3"));
    player->setPlaylist(playlist);
    player->play();
}
```

In mainwindow.cpp:

```
TransitiousPlayer player;
player.play();
```

In main i also call:

```
qRegisterMetaType<TransitiousPlayer>();
```

If i only try to compile transitiousplayer.cpp, it says: "Target debug/transitiousplayer.obj doesn't exist."

Comment: Can you sho your project file, provided you are using qmake? Which OS is this? OT: Fwiw, "Transitious" is not an English word to my knowledge.

Comment: I added the file manually to the makefile, and it worked for me. The OS is Windows and I'm using Qt creator. Are there any properties for c++ classes in Qt Creator? Maybe a "compile" checkbox? "Transitious" is just a fantasy name and working title.

Comment: you can add source and header files and they will be added automatically in the background qmake file. If you open the project file up yourself, you will see that the `HEADERS` and `SOURCES` variables are there filled in. You can also customize them manually, and it will be reparsed automatically for you while regenerating the project tree. Check if the necessary files are added in there.

Answer (score 12):

Probably too late to help, but I had the same issue and am also new to QT (5.2.0).

For some reason, if the makefile is already made, in my situation, it wouldn't add it to the makefile, even if you select 'Clean', which is what I assumed Clean would do.

The solution that worked for me was to manually delete the contents of the build directory and hit build again, in which case it recreates it. I am not sure what clean is supposed to do if not this.

I had a project with a couple of classes, which i built and ran, then made a new class with File->New File.. C++ class. Wrote my class and press run again.
Got that my constructor was missing. Hit build on just that file and got the same Target Debug/...obj doesn't exist.
Checked the pro file and the class source and header names were present, checked the disk, they were there, checked the Makefile.Debug and there was no trace of those files. Hit clean, it didn't change the makefile.
Deleted the contents of the build-Projectname-Desktop-qt_5_2_0.. directory, hit run, and it built and ran without issue.

Answer (score 5):

Posted for future reference: I ran into this problem after adding a new class file, to get the new file to compile you have to run qmake under the Build menu.

Comment: That's why my main routine is `add class` => `run qmake`

Comment: @Tim shoot I saw the above answer first. This sounds cleaner I'll try it next time.

Answer (score 1):

At Qt project view, select "run qmake" again. Then everything is O.K.