# Linker error in simple Qt C++ application

Tags: c++, qt, linker, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile some relatively simple code in Qt C++ but I'm getting the following linker error and can't figure out what the issue is.

> main.obj:-1: erreur : LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "class QUuid __cdecl uuid::fromString(class QString const &)"
>   (?fromString@uuid@@YA?AVQUuid@@ABVQString@@@Z) referenced in function _main

Other files compiles fine but somehow these two (uuid.h/uuid.cpp) have this error.

Also if that's relevant, if I right-click on "uuid.cpp" in Qt Editor and select "Compile", I get this error, which also doesn't happen for other cpp files:

> Start : "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" -f Makefile.Debug debug/uuid.obj
>   Error: Target debug/uuid.obj doesn't exist.

Any idea what the issue could be?

**uuid.h**

```
#ifndef UUID_H
#define UUID_H

#include <stable.h>


namespace uuid {

QUuid fromString(const QString& s);

}

#endif // UUID_H
```

**uuid.cpp**

```
#include <stable.h>
#include "uuid.h"

namespace uuid {

QUuid fromString(const QString& s) {
    // ....
}

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stable.h>
#include "uuid.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QUuid test = uuid::fromString("f601c97e494a46a7b393bb0366e679a1");

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: The makefiles in the build folder are out of date: that's why you can't compile uuid.cpp into uuid.obj. Re-run qmake on the project or ideally remove the build folder and build it then. This question is deficient without the `.pro` file.

Comment: @KubaOber, yes thank you removing the build folder, and in particular the make files, was the solution as explained there - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21933761/561309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the build folder, and in particular the make files, fixed the issue. Running the Clean command from Qt Creator was not enough.